# 12V to 3V parallel fairy LEDs

Tags: led, resistors

I need to connect 3 rows of "fairy" LED (3V) lights connected in parallel from the same power source of 12V to different grounds that work as dimmers, using a Magic Home RGBW Wifi Controller to regulate the intensity of each row using the RGB ground.

What resistance do I need to add to the circuit to avoid burning the LED taking in consideration they should not go over 5V.

Comment: please draw a diagram of what you are thinking

Answer (score 1):

Typical small LEDs will consume max 20mA. Target 10mA to be sure you dont burn them out.

R= (12 - 3) / ( # of LEDs x 0.010)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, the # of LEDs is per row or in total ? thank you

Comment: That would be per row

Comment: So I would need to add a 60ohm resistance per row in series with the power that goes to each row ? thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't know.  You haven't said how many LED's there are in each string!

Comment: Sorry, you are right, there are 30 LEDs per row. thank you for the help

Comment: (12 - 3) / ( 30 * 0.01) = 30  ohms.    There's a power consideration also.   P=I V = (0.01*30) * 9 =2.7 watts   That's actually quite alot of power to dissipate.  You'd need MINIMUM 5W resistor to avoid a hot-to-the-touch component.

Comment: Can you re-arrange your individual 30 LED strings to be 3 strings of 10 LED's each???   If you can do that you can set them up in a series-parallel arrangement (3 strings of 10 parallel LED's, each string in series)   This would allow for a much reduced power loss in the resistor  because you only need drop 3V on the resistor instead of 9V, and the current would only be 10 * 0.01 = 100mA instead of 30 * 0.01 = 300mA  In this case it would be  P=3 * 0.3 = 1W

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I will consider both options for the desired outcome. I assume I connect each resistor at the power line in series right ? thank you once again.

Comment: Yes - Each resistor is in series.  If you are not sure, sketch out the circuit and post it.

Answer (score 0):

3 from 12 is 9.

You need 9V worth of resistance, Find the current the strings need and use Ohm's law.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the issue is that I want to use a Magic Home RGBW Wifi Controller to control each row of "fairy" light intensity. This controller have a common power but different ground for each color. So do I need 3 bucks ? or better just to use resistance in serie?

Comment: it's probably best to use the resistor in that case,  buck converters have capacitors which will mess up your light show,.

Comment: thank you very much for the help.